# Can Twilio Add-ons be enabled/disabled via API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I can't find any documentation suggesting they can, but similar functionality exists for most other resources in the API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [installing Add-ons](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/add-ons#installing-an-add-on) is done only via console. You will see two things on the screen.

1. What API's this will be enabled on-- listed under Supported Products
2. Whether or not the Add-on is Installed or not

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. A more robust and reliable interface for Add-ons would be a great addition to future versions of the API

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I'll be sure to share it with the team!